# Python Web Scraping saving Tik Tok video from url

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to save videos from this url:

Original:

```
https://api2.musical.ly/aweme/v1/play/?video_id=v09044a20000beeff4c108gs7sflfdug
```

Link changes to this:

```
http://v16.muscdn.com/3d238aa3e1c34000ce53792155cd0e15/5bcf3070/video/tos/maliva/tos-maliva-v-0068/e5a1ab74d0b54f97b3578924a428e58d/
```

The video is from TikTok. When you go to the url, it instantly redirects you to another url. The other url is the one I want in order to save the video. However, the url it directs you to does not have a "view html source" option. I can inspect the element and that shows it has a video tag, but I cannot find a way to save the url between the tag. I am using python and beautifulsoup. I tried to do this with selenium, but to no effect.

Comment: `requests.get(url).url` can get the url after redirect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Edit:

The link that it redirects to changes all the time! as of 27/08/2019, the link below works...

If you get `Access denied` you should check the link once again...

I think you should use other libraries for saving videos...

For example (in Python 3+):

```
import urllib.request


vid_url = "http://v19.muscdn.com/21b98c731608b8aa296ec31468c26dd1/5d652a88/video/tos/maliva/tos-maliva-v-0068/e5a1ab74d0b54f97b3578924a428e58d/?rc=amdvdnY7NDdpaDMzNTczM0ApdSlINzU2NTM0MzM2MzM1MzQ1b2k5ZmU5Z2c1ZGY5ZmQzPGZAaUBoNnYpQGczdilAZjY1QHJjYzRkLWBjYl8tLV4xNnNzOmk0NTU1LjQtLi4uMTQ0NTYtOiM2MDAtXjQzXzMxMTFeMWEzYSNvIzphLW8jOmAtbyMwLl4%3D"

urllib.request.urlretrieve(vid_url, "your_video_name.mp4")
```

If you insist on using selenium you can add options like this:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
   "download.default_directory": r"C:\Users\xxx\downloads\Test",
   "download.prompt_for_download": False,
   "download.directory_upgrade": True,
   "safebrowsing.enabled": True
})
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: i ran the request code and had error: ` http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)

HTTPError: Forbidden` - is it because the link expired? Thanks

Comment: @YJZ Yes you are correct the link has expired. I have updated the link to fit OP's question. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you @Moshe Slavin! I updated the link and still have the same error - is there something I can test? (When I put that url into browser, it says `Access to v16.tiktokcdn.com was denied`) Let me know please. Thank you so much!

Comment: @YJZ the link has changed again!

Comment: can you please tell me how can i download the video without watermark from video url?

Comment: @MateenChaudhry The real question is if the video on the server is with the watermark or not!